# Correcting paper size in Microsoft Word without losing the existing page formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

A friend of mine wrote a very long essay in Microsoft Word 2007 only to discover that he has written it in letter-size pages instead of A4 ones. How is it possible to correct the paper size without the paragraphs and pictures getting out of whack?

Comment: Have you tried to change the paper size? What version of Word are you using? [Edit]ing your question with any details of what you have tried can help you get a useful answer.

Comment: He uses Microsoft Word 2007. He tried to change the paper size but didn't save the result because it looked horrible. It's his masters' thesis and it's more than 100 pages.

Comment: What is the problem when printing it on A4 paper?

Comment: It leaves unwanted margins at the top and bottom of paper. It's his thesis, otherwise it wouldn't be too big a problem.

Comment: How do you expect getting rid of the margins without changing the flow of the paragraphs? Either the margins remain, or there will be more text per page, and that will affect the layout.

Comment: I don't really know! I'm just looking for some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Letter** is 8.5" x 11", and **A4** is **8.27"** x **11.69"**. If he had set a **1"** margin all around, he had effectively **7.5"** x **10"** for his text.

Perhaps if he changes the page size to **A4** and sets a custom **0.77"** (0.38" + 0.39") x **1.69"** (0.84" + 0.85") margin, the content won't move around/re-flow as much.

Answer (score 0):

we can solve it in printing only by go to file print then from each page for one paper choose Appropriate paper size to a4 then print

Comment: While this method works it would take a ridiculously long time to do. The method in the accepted answer is much faster.